# Canvas with react-refresh

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-konva

I use @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
along with react-konva. When updating props, such as element coordinates, nothing is updated. I need to reload the page for check updates. How can I solve this problem? Everything else is updated except the canvas elements

my webpack dev server config:

```
exports.loadJS = () => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        include: [path.resolve(process.env.projectPath)],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    targets: 'defaults'
                  }
                ],
                '@babel/preset-react'
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: [path.resolve(process.env.projectPath), path.resolve(process.env.projectPath, '/public/scripts')],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    targets: 'defaults'
                  }
                ],
                '@babel/preset-react'
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      typescript: {
        diagnosticOptions: {
          semantic: true,
          syntactic: true
        },
        mode: 'write-references'
      }
    })
  ]
})

exports.devServer = () => ({
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 3300,
    client: {
      overlay: {
        errors: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin()]
})
```

I tried change refresh plugin, but its not help me